# Debugged process not break on breakpoint

Tags: anti-debugging

I launch a game process then I suspend the process and restore the hooks in ntdll.dll then I attach debugger to the process and resume the process. Next I see debugger catch the 0xC0000005(access violation) exception on thread [DbgUiRemoteBreakin] and did not break on any breakpoint I seted (I had set a break point on [DbgUiRemoteBreakin]). And can not single step debug. So is there any infomation about how to solve it here?

Comment: Sounds like you have more anti-debug to disable before you can properly debug, does the game have anticheat or just antidebug?  Would help to know the name of the game and if it's Steam or non-Steam